"Remember Me" functionality usng PassportJS with express-session and connect-redis not working on browser restart
passport.use(
  'local',
  new LocalStrategy(
    strategyOptions,
    async (
      req: Request,
      email: string,
      password: string,
      done: (error: any, user?: any, options?: IVerifyOptions) => void,
    ) => {
      try {
        if (req.body.rememberMe) {
          req.session.cookie.maxAge = 86400000;
          req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + 86400000);
          logger.info('SETTING MAX AGE');
        } else {
          // @ts-ignore
          req.session.cookie.expires = false;
          logger.info('CLEARING MAX AGE');
        }
        req.session.save(() => {});
        const account = await AuthService.getByEmail(email);
        if (!account) {
          return done(null, null, { message: 'Incorrect email or password' });
        }
        if (!(await isHashEqual(account?.password as string, password))) {
          return done(null, null, { message: 'Incorrect email or password' });
        }
        const result = account.toJSON();
        delete result.password;
        return done(null, result);
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    },
  ),
);


The above code is my passport local strategy to login via email and password

I checked remember me option and did a login from my frontend
When I closed browser and started it again, it is still logging me off

This is what my session handler looks like
import RedisStore from 'connect-redis';
import expressSession from 'express-session';

import { redisClient } from './redisClient';

const store = new RedisStore({ client: redisClient });

export const sessionOptions = {
  name: 'ch',
  secret: 'something',
  resave: false,
  rolling: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: undefined,
    sameSite: true,
    secure: false,
  },
  store,
};

export const sessionHandler = expressSession(sessionOptions);


Regardless of whether I set "Remember Me" or not, when I exit the browser and go back, it asks me to login again
This is what my cookie stored on redis looks like
"{\"cookie\":{\"secure\":false,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\",\"sameSite\":true},\"passport\":{\"user\":\"a0baee7b-4b97-4efb-b068-d7436167fba2\"}}"

Can someone kindly suggest how to make this feature work?
